# I need advice for my discord clone (or messaging platform, if you will) written in typescript

Tags: typescript, macos

Let me break down what this is for you.

This code defines TypeScript interfaces and namespaces for a WebSocket API used in a chat or messaging system. It appears to be defining the structure of messages exchanged between a client and a server in a chat application.

Now, the problem, is on line 39, I get this error

> "Namespace 'API.WSResponse' has no exported member 'UserDelete'."

Here's the code. I'd highly appreciate if someone could fix the error for me, if not, explain whats wrong. Here's the code.

```
declare namespace API {
    export interface ToWSAPI {
      'CHANNEL_CREATE': WSPayload.ChannelCreate;
      'CHANNEL_DELETE': WSPayload.ChannelDelete;
      'GUILD_CREATE': WSPayload.GuildCreate;
      'GUILD_DELETE': WSPayload.GuildDelete;
      'GUILD_MEMBER_ADD': WSPayload.GuildMemberAdd;
      'GUILD_MEMBER_REMOVE': WSPayload.GuildMemberRemove;
      'GUILD_UPDATE': WSPayload.GuildUpdate;
      'INVITE_CREATE': WSPayload.InviteCreate;
      'MESSAGE_CREATE': WSPayload.MessageCreate;
      'MESSAGE_DELETE': WSPayload.MessageDelete;
      'MESSAGE_UPDATE': WSPayload.MessageUpdate;
      'READY': WSPayload.Ready;
      'TYPING_START': WSPayload.TypingStart;
      'USER_DELETE': WSPayload.UserDelete;
      'USER_UPDATE': WSPayload.UserUpdate;
    }
  
    export interface OnWSAPI {
      'disconnect': any;
      'message': string;
    }
  
    export interface FromWSAPI {
      'CHANNEL_CREATE': WSResponse.ChannelCreate;
      'CHANNEL_DELETE': WSResponse.ChannelDelete;
      'GUILD_CREATE': WSResponse.GuildCreate;
      'GUILD_DELETE': WSResponse.GuildDelete;
      'GUILD_MEMBER_ADD': WSResponse.GuildMemberAdd;
      'GUILD_MEMBER_REMOVE': WSResponse.GuildMemberRemove;
      'GUILD_UPDATE': WSResponse.GuildUpdate;
      'INVITE_CREATE': WSResponse.InviteCreate;
      'MESSAGE_CREATE': WSResponse.MessageCreate;
      'MESSAGE_DELETE': WSResponse.MessageDelete;
      'MESSAGE_UPDATE': WSResponse.MessageUpdate;
      'READY': WSResponse.Ready;
      'TYPING_START': WSResponse.TypingStart;
      'USER_DELETE': WSResponse.UserDelete;
      'USER_UPDATE': WSResponse.UserUpdate;
    }
  
    // payload to server
    // - only needed properties
    export namespace WSPayload {
      export interface ChannelCreate {
        name: string;
        guildId: string;
      }
      export interface ChannelDelete {
        guildId: string;
        channelId: string;
      }
      export interface GuildCreate {
        name: string;
      }
      export interface GuildDelete {
        guildId: string;
      }
      export interface GuildUpdate {
        guildId: string;
        payload: Partial<Entity.Guild>;
      }
      export interface GuildMemberAdd {
        inviteCode: string;
      }
      export interface GuildMemberRemove {
        userId: string;
        guildId: string;
      }
      export interface InviteCreate {
        guildId: string;
      }
      export interface MessageCreate {
        channelId: string;
        content: string;
      }
      export interface MessageDelete {
        messageId: string;
      }
      export interface MessageUpdate {
        messageId: string;
        payload: Partial<Entity.Message>;
      }
      export interface Ready {
        token: string;
      }
      export interface TypingStart {
        channelId: string;
      }
      export interface UserDelete {}
      export interface UserUpdate {
        payload: Partial<Entity.User>;
      }
    }
    
    // full data, not payload
    // - data that will be likely stored and used by redux on client side
    export namespace WSResponse {
      export interface ChannelCreate {
        channel: Entity.Channel;
        creatorId: string;
      }
      export interface ChannelDelete {
        channelId: string;
        guildId: string;
      }
      export interface GuildCreate {
        guild: Entity.Guild;
      }
      export interface GuildDelete {
        guildId: string;
      }
      export interface GuildUpdate {
        guildId: string;
        payload: Partial<Entity.Guild>;
      }
      export interface GuildMemberAdd {
        guildId: string;
        member: Entity.User;
      }
      export interface InviteCreate {
        invite: Entity.Invite;
      }
      export interface GuildMemberRemove {
        userId: string;
      }
      export interface MessageCreate {
        message: Entity.Message;
      }
      export interface MessageDelete {
        messageId: string;
      }
      export interface MessageUpdate {
        messageId: string;
        payload: Partial<Entity.Message>;
      }
      export interface Ready {
        user: Entity.User;
      }
      export interface TypingStart {
        channelId: string;
        userId: string;
      }
      export interface UserUpdate {
        payload: Partial<Entity.User>;
      }
    }
  }
```

Well this is just APIs so..

Comment: The error seems so self-explanatory that I'm confused by your confusion.  It's saying that your namespace `API.WSResponse`, doesn't `export` a `UserDelete` interface, and that's correct.  There is a `UserDelete` interface but it's in `API.WSPayload`, not `API.WSResponse`.  Somewhere in there is your problem, and you're the one who knows what the intent is, so you're in the best position to fix it.  You could move `UserDelete` to the other namespace, or import it from the right place, etc.  Does that fully address the question, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear.

Here in the `FromWSAPI` interface you set `'USER_DELETE'` to `WSResponse.UserDelete`

```js
'USER_DELETE': WSResponse.UserDelete;
```

but

> "Namespace 'API.WSResponse' has no exported member 'UserDelete'.

There is no exported member `UserDelete` in the `WSResponse` name space, you probably forgot to add the `UserDelete` interface to `WSResponse`

```js
export namespace WSResponse {
 // ...
 export interface UserDelete {
 //...
 }
}
```

Note also that the interface `UserDelete` of `WSPayload` namespace is empty .